# Different transactional behaviour with Spring-data JPA and Mysql on one environment

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jta

We are facing a weird transactional issue with Spring data JPA and Mysql

We have a table `tableA` in which we are storing the request execution status for an SDP (SDP is another entity and is referenced by a `sdp_id` in `tableA`)
Consider that request comes very first time for an SDP. The `tableA` does not have any entry for this SDP.
We add a new entry to `tableA` with status `IN_PROGRESS` in a *new transaction*. The purpose of doing it in a new transaction is if any other request comes for same SDP, the status `IN_PROGRESS` should be visible so that duplicate flow is not triggered for the same SDP
After the business logic is complete, we update the `tableA` entry by setting `status=COMPLETED` for the same row.
This is working fine for all but one environment. On this one environment, instead of updating the same row as `COMPLETED`, it is inserting a new row with status. So, at the end there are 2 rows for same SDP with statuses `IN_PROGRESS` and `COMPLETED`.

We have confirmed that all the environments have exact same version of JRE and Mysql. What can be the reason for this difference in transactional behaviour just on one environment?